# Android - limit heap size to 16MB for testing purposes?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have created an Android app and I now want to make sure that it never goes above 16MB of heap usage.

Unfortunately for this task my device has a much bigger heap than the minimum of 16MB, it has at least 32MB.

When I track the allocations it just keeps allocating and allocating and seldom garbage collects which makes it hard to track down memory leaks.

I have tried to use various profilers but it is not easy.

Preferrably I would like to back and forth between activities and just see the heap go up and then back down so that there are no memory leaks but since the garbage collection is postponed until it is really needed this seems hard to do.

Is it possible to limit the heap size to 16MB on a 32MB heap size device for testing purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use an Android Virtual Device, as you can configure the heap size in the Android emulator. It is in the advanced options when creating an AVD.

However if you must test this on a real device you can simulate having a smaller heap by creating a memory leak of heap memory on startup. Make sure you keep a strong reference to the object you allocate so it isn't garbage collected.

On a device with 32MB heap size, if you create a 16MB leak on startup this will leave the remaining 16MB of heap space for your application to use.